# solr reverse proxy Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, solr

I am trying to setup Apache2 as Reverse Proxy for solr. Apache and Solr are on the same machine. Apache is serving other stuff as regular web server, too.

solsearch config file in `/etc/apache2/config.d/`

```
# Proxy specific settings
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /solrsearch http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse
ProxyPassReverse /solrsearch http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse
```

Now trying http://localhost/solsearch gives me the first page of http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse, but with broken layout (like css missing).

Result: `error.log` of apache:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/solr, referer: [http://192.168.1.150/solrsearch]
```

Comment: What location are the css files etc trying to load from?

Comment: First make sure you understand the basics: http://www.michael--martinez.com/computers/reverseproxy.html

Comment: @Shane Madden: It should get all files from [localhost:8983/slor], but then it suddenly looks for them in the normal www folder...

Answer (score 4):

The links from the HTML content page for the CSS and other files are probably absolute paths - so they're linked to `/solr/path/to/css` instead of `path/to/css`.

You should be able to solve this by adding another `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass /solrsearch http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse
ProxyPassReverse /solrsearch http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse
ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8983/solr
```

But, you should be careful that that's not exposing more content than you want exposed if this is a publicly available server.

Answer (score 3):

just to tag on here. The following proxy configuration permits the default Solr browser to operate (with CSS, javascript, etc) **without** giving access to the admin functions:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    # Proxy specific settings
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # permit:
    #  * queries
    #  * javascript
    #  * css
    #  * term vectors
    # restrict:
    #  * all other traffic (admin, etc)

    ProxyPassMatch "/solr/(.*/browse)" http://localhost:8983/solr/$1
    ProxyPassMatch "/solr/(.*/terms)" http://localhost:8983/solr/$1
    ProxyPassMatch "/solr/(.*/admin/file)" http://localhost:8983/solr/$1
    ProxyPass /solr/js http://localhost:8983/solr/js
    ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8983/solr
</IfModule>
```

This is working on my Solr 6.1.0 system.